# suPHP upgrade causing 500 internal server error

Tags: apache, config

I have my server perform a yum update every night. Last night, it updated suPHP to the newest version:
`Oct 16 01:25:43 Updated: mod_suphp-0.7.1-1.el5.art.x86_64`

This update has caused my website to throw a 500 internal server error. From what I've been able to find, I should only have to change the last two lines in my suphp.conf file to include quotes, which I did. But after restarting apache, I still get error 500. None of my files or directories are set to 777, so that's not the issue either. Does anybody else know what has changed in the newest suPHP release that would cause my config to no longer work? Thanks. Here is what my conf file looks like now:

```
[global]
;Path to logfile
logfile=/var/log/suphp.log

;Loglevel
loglevel=warn

;User Apache is running as
webserver_user=apache

;Path all scripts have to be in
docroot=/

;Path to chroot() to before executing script
;chroot=/mychroot

; Security options
allow_file_group_writeable=false
allow_file_others_writeable=false
allow_directory_group_writeable=false
allow_directory_others_writeable=false

;Check wheter script is within DOCUMENT_ROOT
check_vhost_docroot=true

;Send minor error messages to browser
errors_to_browser=true

;PATH environment variable
env_path=/bin:/usr/bin

;Umask to set, specify in octal notation
umask=0022

; Minimum UID
min_uid=500

; Minimum GID
min_gid=500

; Use correct permissions for mod_userdir sites
handle_userdir=true

[handlers]
;Handler for php-scripts
;x-httpd-php=php:/usr/bin/php-cgi
php5-script="php:/usr/bin/php-cgi"

;Handler for CGI-scripts
x-suphp-cgi="execute:!self"
```

I am using atomic rocket turtle repos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it. The following line is deprecated, so I just had to delete it:
`handle_userdir=true`